# How to embed ICC_Profile in TiffOutputSet

Tags: java, image-processing

I am trying to use Commons-Imaging (used to be Sanselan) to write a tiff file. I am trying to add an ICC_Profile to the header. Here is the code I have:

```
    TiffImageMetadata tmeta = (TiffImageMetadata) metadata;
    TiffOutputSet outputSet = tmeta.getOutputSet();

    TagInfoUndefined TIFF_TAG_ICC = TiffOutputField.EXIF_TAG_CURRENT_ICCPROFILE;
    byte[] profileBytes = ICC_Profile.getInstance(pathToFile).getData();
    TiffOutputField field = new TiffOutputField(TIFF_TAG_ICC, FieldType.UNDEFINED, 1, profileBytes);
    TiffOutputDirectory exifDirectory = outputSet.getOrCreateExifDirectory();
    exifDirectory.removeField(TiffOutputField.EXIF_TAG_CURRENT_ICCPROFILE);
    exifDirectory.add(field);

    TiffImageWriterLossless writerLossless = new TiffImageWriterLossless(bytes);
    writerLossless.write(new FileOutputStream(resultingFilePath), outputSet);
```

I believe that using TiffImageWriterLossless is the correct way to do this, but the tag that I add isn't recognized.

Does somebody out there know where I am going wrong here?

My next attempt:

```
TiffImageMetadata tmeta = (TiffImageMetadata) metadata;
    TiffOutputSet outputSet = tmeta.getOutputSet();
    byte iccBytes[] = ICC_Profile.getInstance(pathToIccFile);
    TagInfoUndefined ICC_INFO = TiffConstants.EXIF_TAG_INTER_COLOR_PROFILE;
    TiffOutputField field = new TiffOutputField(ICC_INFO, FieldType.UNDEFINED, iccBytes.length, iccBytes);
    TiffOutputDirectory exifDirectory = outputSet.getOrCreateExifDirectory();
    exifDirectory.add(field); 
    TiffImageWriterLossless writerLossless = new TiffImageWriterLossless(imageBytes);
    writerLossless.write(new FileOutputStream(resultingFilePath), outputSet);
```

Image Magick identify:

```
identify: Unknown field with tag 34675 (0x8773) encountered. `TIFFReadCustomDirectory' @ warning/tiff.c/TIFFWarnings/824.
```

I'd be happy to do the legwork if somebody can point me in the right direction. When I looked at the Commons-Imaging docs it is stated:

> Most other libraries offer little or incomplete support for ICC Profiles. Commons Imaging can extract and (simply) parse embedded ICC Profiles. Moreover, it applies the ICC profile by default, coverting read images to sRGB. This means images are color-corrected by default. see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Color_Consortium, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/sRGB

This seems to be referring only to reading ICC_Profiles?

ExifTool seems to pick up the Adobe RGB Profile:

```
ExifTool Version Number         : 9.45
File Name                       : straw.tif
Directory                       : .
File Size                       : 130 kB
File Modification Date/Time     : 2014:01:04 09:56:03-06:00
File Access Date/Time           : 2014:01:04 10:02:03-06:00
File Inode Change Date/Time     : 2014:01:04 09:56:18-06:00
File Permissions                : rw-------
File Type                       : TIFF
MIME Type                       : image/tiff
Exif Byte Order                 : Little-endian (Intel, II)
Image Width                     : 502
Image Height                    : 564
Bits Per Sample                 : 8 8 8
Compression                     : LZW
Photometric Interpretation      : RGB
Strip Offsets                   : (Binary data 765 bytes, use -b option to extract)
Samples Per Pixel               : 3
Rows Per Strip                  : 5
Strip Byte Counts               : (Binary data 477 bytes, use -b option to extract)
X Resolution                    : 300
Y Resolution                    : 300
Resolution Unit                 : inches
Profile CMM Type                : ADBE
Profile Version                 : 2.1.0
Profile Class                   : Display Device Profile
Color Space Data                : RGB
Profile Connection Space        : XYZ
Profile Date Time               : 2000:08:11 19:51:59
Profile File Signature          : acsp
Primary Platform                : Apple Computer Inc.
CMM Flags                       : Not Embedded, Independent
Device Manufacturer             : none
Device Model                    : 
Device Attributes               : Reflective, Glossy, Positive, Color
Rendering Intent                : Perceptual
Connection Space Illuminant     : 0.9642 1 0.82491
Profile Creator                 : ADBE
Profile ID                      : 0
Profile Copyright               : Copyright 2000 Adobe Systems Incorporated
Profile Description             : Adobe RGB (1998)
Media White Point               : 0.95045 1 1.08905
Media Black Point               : 0 0 0
Red Tone Reproduction Curve     : (Binary data 14 bytes, use -b option to extract)
Green Tone Reproduction Curve   : (Binary data 14 bytes, use -b option to extract)
Blue Tone Reproduction Curve    : (Binary data 14 bytes, use -b option to extract)
Red Matrix Column               : 0.60974 0.31111 0.01947
Green Matrix Column             : 0.20528 0.62567 0.06087
Blue Matrix Column              : 0.14919 0.06322 0.74457
Image Size                      : 502x564
```

But if I open the same TIFF file with GIMP - it only finds the default sRGB ColorSpace.

Frustrating. ExifTool finds the profile and apparently reads it, but GIMP doesn't find it. It's useless if it can't be picked up by popular Image Editors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it to work. The mistake I made was when I got the TiffOutputDirectory, I called getOrCreateExifDirectory, but it should have been getOrCreateRootDirectory.

Here is the correct code:

```
TiffImageMetadata tmeta = (TiffImageMetadata) metadata;
    TiffOutputSet outputSet = tmeta.getOutputSet();
    byte iccBytes[] = Util.getAdobe98ProfileBytes();
    TagInfoUndefined ICC_INFO = TiffConstants.EXIF_TAG_INTER_COLOR_PROFILE;
    TiffOutputField field = new TiffOutputField(ICC_INFO, FieldType.UNDEFINED, iccBytes.length, iccBytes);
    TiffOutputDirectory rootDirectory = outputSet.getOrCreateRootDirectory();
    rootDirectory.removeField(ICC_INFO);
    rootDirectory.add(field);

    TiffImageWriterLossless writerLossless = new TiffImageWriterLossless(imageBytes);
    writerLossless.write(new FileOutputStream(resultingFilePath), outputSet);
```

This is how you embed an ICC_Profile in TiffOutputSet.

Comment: I have a related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58523546/icc-profile-set-data). Any ideas ?