# Update Tiff-Metadata using Apache Commons-Imaging/Sanselan

Tags: java, image, image-processing, tiff

I will modify and add Tiff-Tags to existing tif-files with java. JAI imageio crashed, because it could not deal with certain tags from Tiff 6.0. Apache Commons-Imaging seems to be able to deal with these tags. But I have no idea, how to do that. I found a post here, I used for beginning ([How to embed ICC_Profile in TiffOutputSet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20895911/how-to-embed-icc-profile-in-tiffoutputset)). 
Using the example code creates an image, which I can't open because of an LZW error. If I use the Imaging.writeImage(...) methods, It changes the color model from 8Bit to 24Bit and the Exif metadata hase gone.

What i have done is:

```
bufferedImage = Imaging.getBufferedImage(srcTiff);
byte[] imageBytes = Imaging.writeImageToBytes(tifFile, imageFormat, optional_params)
exifDirectory = tiffOutputSet.getOrCreateRootDirectory();
...
TiffImageWriterLossLess lossLessWriter = new TiffImageWriterLossless(imageBytes);
os = new FileOutputStream(tmpFile);
os = new BufferedOutputStream(os);
lossLessWriter.writeImage(bufferedImage, os, image_params);
```

Playing around with image_params, like compression or defining the outputset as params, results in different issues. But one is constant, the destImage is bigger then the src image, even when the source image is 24 bit like the dest image.

How could I get Commons-Imaging work for me?

Comment: hi, did you get answer to this ? were you able to add tiff tag ?

Answer (score 0):

I can respond to the **destImage** bigger than the **src**, it is because TIFF images have a compression that is not carried over when the image is read into memory. On writing the image back to storage, you must apply the compression explicitly.